# If every non-zero ring homomorphism $\phi: K\rightarrow S$ is injective, $K$ is field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

If every ring homomorphism $\phi: K\rightarrow S$ is injective, $K$ is field.

PS: $K$ is a commutative ring with unity, and my definition of homomorphism includes $\phi(1_{K})=1_{S}$.

My idea is to fix an arbitrary $k\in K$ and construct a homomorphism $\phi$ such that, by $\phi,$ I can find the inverse $k^{-1}$... But I don't got it.

Comment: You are trying to show that $K$ is a field, not $S$. So finding inverse of $s \in S$ will not help.

Comment: @AnuragA fixed. Just typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ isn't a field then there is an $s\in K\backslash\{0\}$ without an inverse. Then the non-zero ideal $sK$ does not contain $1$, and the quotient map $\phi: K \rightarrow K/sK$ is injective.

Comment: Why $sK$ does not contain $1$?

Comment: If it did we would have sk=1 for some k in K. But then ks=1 also so k is clearly an inverse to s, but we started with an s without an inverse.

Comment: Sorry for another question, but how can I finish the question? I didn't got it

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ be a nonzero ideal in $K$, consider the quotient map $K \rightarrow K/I$.

Answer (score 0):

Our colleague Mindlack certainly has the right idea, ***+1***; here we flesh out some details:

If $K$ is a commutative unital ring which is *not* a field, then it is possessed of a non-zero, non-invertible element; that is,

$\exists 0 \ne u \in K, \; \forall v \in K, uv \ne 1_K, \tag 1$

or, equivalently,

$\exists 0 \ne u \in K, \; \not \exists v \in K, uv = 1_K; \tag 2$

it follows that the principal ideal

$(u) = uK = Ku \ne K, \tag 3$

since

$1_K \notin (u); \tag 4$

furthermore

$0 \ne u = u1_K \in uK = (u) \Longrightarrow (u) \ne \{0\}, \tag 5$

and we conclude that $(u)$ is a non-trivial, proper ideal of $K$.

Now consider the cannonical projection homomorphism

$\pi:K \to K/(u), \; \pi(k) = k + (u); \tag 6$

since

$\pi(0) = \pi(u) = (u) \in K/(u), \tag 7$

$\pi$ is not injective, contrary to hypothesis; thus every $u \in K$ is invertible, and $K$ is a field.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: Ok, I understood almost everything, but the final part is confuse.
Why "$\pi$ is not injective" contradicts my hypothesis? We are dealing with homomorphisms $\phi:R\rightarrow S$, where $S$ is some fixed ring, but $\pi$ maps to $K/uK$

Comment: @MateusRocha:  first, $\pi$ is not injective because it maps two distinct elements of $K$, $u$ and $0$, to the zero element of $K/(u)$.  As for your second question, you assumed every homomorphism $\phi:K \to S$ ***is*** injective; my proof is by contradiction, so when I show $\pi$ is ***not*** injective (in the case $K$ is not a field), I go against your assumption.  Is that Clear?  Cheers!

Comment: @MateusRocha:  I didn't know $S$ was fixed and I'm not sure the result holds if it is.  I could be wrong though . . .

Comment: Maybe it wasn't fixed and I am misinterpretating it

Comment: @MateusRocha:  maybe.  Something to learn about, anyway!